# Database Design model a Customer, Cook, User relationship

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am very confused and I have read a lot on internet & SO but I cant figure out. In this design, scalability is an important task for me.

I am making a portal where people can offer to sell their food or can go to this portal to buy food.

I am thinking about following 3 options:

1. Make 3 tables. User, Customer, Cook.
2. Make 2 tables. User, Customer.
3. Make 2 tables. Customer. Cook

I created a User table mostly for security because I dont want secret data to reside in Customer or Cook table.

Problem is that a Cook can also be a customer.

I am thinking of approach 1. How do I model it. Do I use recursive approach. Recursive approach works with Employee and Manager idea (standard textbook example) but it seems strange here.

In approach 2, I use 1 table and I do not differentiate between cook and customer. Not making this distinct, seems like a bad idea somehow.

Approach 3 is possible but I cant think in my mind, how it can work

A user table is like this:

[image]

A customer table is like this:

[image]

Comment: Someone can be a user, customer and a cook. It would be better as 3 tables as you can easily separate out what the data is relevant to.

Comment: This is a faq, google my SO comments for database subtyping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend using the three table approach to separate data specific to each role.

- The User table contains data that is common to both roles, such as the user's name.
- The other two tables hold only role-specific data.

The relationships between User and Customer (or User and Cook) are one-to-zero-or-one. So for each User there may be a Customer or a Cook record, or both if the User fulfils both roles.

[image]

Diagram made here: https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/schema/t_JngpUcm0-w_dbnW3FzsA  [Disclaimer: I work for QuickDatabaseDiagrams]

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Yesterday I ended up thinking about exactly the same approach.  Good to have my opinion reaffirmed.

Comment: btw QuickDatabaseDiagram approach to making database diagram using code looks really cool. I will use it for my next diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one more column in user table "userType"[buyer/seller/both].This will help to know current user is acting as a buyer , seller or both. This will help to model system flow as well .

Comment: I took a different approach but this could have worked too. Thanks

Comment: I am somehow having the same question today, what is your thought about this today?